# laravel selectpicker selected value reset to first value. why?

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a selectpicker inside a table. I am passing the selected value into it but it shows the first value. why?

```
<td>
    <select name="select[]" id="select" data-selected="224515"
        class="selectpicker form-control select"  data-live-search="true"
        data-show-subtext="true" data-size="5" 
        data-container="body" title="Search Parts..">
        @foreach ($list as $p)
            <option data-id="{{ $p->id }}"
                data-subtext="{{ $p->code }}"
                data-tokens="{{ $p->id }}"
                data-name="{{ $p->name }}" data-price="{{ $p->price }}"
                data-code="{{ $p->code }}">
                {{ $p->name }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selectpicker you're using does not support setting a value like that ([documentation here](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/options/))
You're setting the data-selected attribute which is not supported.

You can use the `@selected` helper from Blade. [Documentation on additional attributes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#additional-attributes)

```
<td>
    <select name="select[]" id="select" data-selected="224515"
        class="selectpicker form-control select"  data-live-search="true"
        data-show-subtext="true" data-size="5" 
        data-container="body" title="Search Parts..">
        @foreach ($list as $p)
            <option data-id="{{ $p->id }}"

                @selected($p->id === 224515)

                data-subtext="{{ $p->code }}"
                data-tokens="{{ $p->id }}"
                data-name="{{ $p->name }}" 
                data-price="{{ $p->price }}"
                data-code="{{ $p->code }}">
                {{ $p->name }}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</td>
```

I assumed the `data-selected` attribute is filled dynamically, so replace the id in the `@selected` with the dynamic stuff.

Comment: Yes, data-selected attribute is filled dynamically and I didn't know data-selected attribute is not supported by selectpicker cause I had a bunch of selectpicker outside of the table where I used data-selected attribute and It just worked regardless not being present in the documentation. Thank you... @selected helper worked inside of table.

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
  <select name="select[]" id="select"
  class="selectpicker form-control select"  data-live-search="true" data-show- 
  subtext="true" data-size="5" data-container="body" title="Search Parts..">
    @foreach ($list as $p)
      <option data-id="{{ $p->id }}" 
        value="{{ $p->value }}" "{{ ( $p->value == "224515") ? 'selected' : '' }}"
        data-subtext="{{ $p->code }}"
        data-tokens="{{ $p->id }}" 
        data-name="{{ $p->name }}" 
        data-price="{{ $p->price }}" 
        data-code="{{ $p->code }}">{{ $p->name }}
      </option>
    @endforeach
</select></td>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).